# Downloading file by using JAX-RS together with ajax and javascript's blob object, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, jax-rs, blob

I trying to download file by using [javascript's Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob), but something weird is happening.
First of all I use **JAX-RS** to send the file from backend, this is my code:

```
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    //creating workbook...

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        wb.write(bos);
        bos.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    return Response.ok(bytes).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "test.xls").build();
```

`bos` is 'ByteArrayOutputStream' object which I create from **Apache POI** workbook. If I use regular way to download this file, i.e. pointing browser to **JAX-RS** resource, everything works fine, but when I try to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/947111 it doesn't work, file being downloaded corrupted.

When I tried to debug it in Chrome's console I paid attention that there's difference in size between **response** object and **Blob** object when I trying convert **response** to **Blob**. Size of the **response** is 4096 bytes,

```
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 17:32:27 GMT
Server: WildFly/8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Content-Length: 4096
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

But when I perform `var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });`, **blob** becomes the size of 7836 bytes, i.e. when I perform `blob.size` in console, I get this size. Downloaded file's size is 7834 bytes. But when I stop debugger at this point `var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);` and point browser in another tab to `downloadURL`, downloaded file's size appear to be 7836 bytes, and appears to be corrupted too.
So, my question is why it doesn't work and why there's difference in size?
I use **Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit)**, but in **Firefox 35.0.1** I have a same behaviour.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. The full code of my client side from [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post/23797348#23797348) which I mentioned above:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: params,
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        // check for a filename
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            }

            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post the xmlhttp implementation for downloading the excel shaeet as attachment. i am also strunggling with the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution? kindly help me.

Comment: Yes, @Musa answer from below helped me, you can see code examples in the comments

Comment: I have seen the link you mentioned on comment, But I have two problem with that. 1- browser can't detect the file type and a file with no icon is dowloaded with a random name. 2- page goes to loading.

Comment: It looks like server side problem, if you using java servlet you can look at this example to serve *.pdf files http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html regarding another framework it should be same, `Media-Type` http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml and `Content-Disposition` type http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml

Comment: page goes to loading, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binary data is converted to text, this corrupts your data.
Currently jQuery.Ajax cannot do a typed ajax request, which is what you need, therefore you'll have to use bare XMLHttpRequest and set the [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType) to `blob` then [`XMLHttpRequest.response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#response) will be the data as a blob

Comment: @anatoly can you post the xmlhttp implementation for downloading the excel shaeet as attachment. i am also strunggling with the same problem.

Comment: @yokks, try this code. It's from pretty old project and I haven't server to check if it's working but it should work. If not, let me know. I'll try to recover server side too. http://pastebin.com/Ju9Vfnwj